# Recursive sequences defined in terms of the other : How to prove that one sequence approaches infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

With the last part, we get that the given sequence $(x/y)$ converges iff $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}   y = \infty$. I can prove that both of the given sequences are increasing by induction, but how do I prove that they are not bounded above? (clearly, if $y$ is not bounded, then $x$ is not by the last relation. Is there a different way to do this? Perhaps via the Squeeze theorem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojaqs.png

Comment: Prove by induction on $n$ that 
$$x_n \ge 2^n$$
$$y_n \ge 2^n$$
for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Comment: @quasi  Hmm.. So I would be proving the statement : For all n, x>=2^n and y>=2^n, by induction? Because I don't think I can prove them one-by-one since x depends upon y and y upon x.

Comment: Right. Prove the _system_ of two inequalities by induction on $n$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.